# Add Apex Plugin Items dynamically?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Apex application, I would like to add some Item Plugins dynamically to a certain page.

In the documentation, Oracle doesn't talk at all about this. It only specifies how to add "standard" items : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_item.htm#AEAPI192

Is possible to add Plugin Items dynamically ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That documentation is for APEX_ITEM, a package that's only useful for generating the HTML for some simple item types. These, however, are not "real" APEX items.

As you have seen, APEX_ITEM does not provide any support for generating items based on a plugin.

A workaround would be to examine the code generated by your item plugin, and based on your analysis of that HTML write your own code to generate the same items yourself using a PL/SQL region or a SQL-based report.

Comment: "examine the code generated by your item plugin, and based on your analysis of that HTML write your own code to generate the same items yourself" Can this approach take into consideration items validations ?

Comment: You would need to code those up as well. It's custom code, after all, so you can't take advantage of many of APEX's declarative features.